# How to read queue instead arrayList by csv-spring?

Tags: java, spring, list, csv, queue

I used spring-csv for read csv file like in example here

[examples](https://www.baeldung.com/java-csv-file-array)

For this target I created this method

```
 public static <T> List<T> loadObjectList(Class<T> type, File file) {
        try {
            CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader().withColumnSeparator('$');
            CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
            MappingIterator<T> readValues = mapper
                    .reader(type)
                    .with(bootstrapSchema).read
                    .readValues(file);
            List<T> values = readValues.readAll();

            return values;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.format("Error occurred while loading object list from file %s", file.getName(), e);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

It works ok for files with 50-60k record-lines.
 But, now I need to read file with 11 million records and process it in any threads.
For threads is better to use Queues, so, how to convert this method to return Queues instead ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> loadObjectList(Class<T> type, File file) {
        try {
            CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader().withColumnSeparator('$');
            CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
            MappingIterator<T> readValues = mapper
                    .reader(type)
                    .with(bootstrapSchema)
                    .readValues(file);

            ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
            readValues.readAll(queue);

            return queue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.format("Error occurred while loading object list from file %s", file.getName(), e);
            return new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
        }
    }
```

readAll(Queue q) can return queue too..